# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(x^2 +1)^{1/2} -2(x^3 + x)^{1/3} +(x^4 + x^2)^{1/4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}[(x^2 +1)^{1/2} -2(x^3 + x)^{1/3} +(x^4 + x^2)^{1/4}]$$

Here's what I've tried:

$$ = \lim_{x\to +\infty} x\left((1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{1/2} - 2(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})^{1/3} +(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{1/4} )\right) = +\infty \cdot 0$$

Which is undefined.

Comment: Have you made any headway?  Have you seen that you can factor an $x$ out of every term?

Comment: yeah i tried it and it still +infinity x  0 which is undifined

Comment: OK, edit into your question that and anything else you tried ([series expansions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595426/series-expansion-of-a-function-at-infinity), attempts at finding bounds, etc) or else this question is likely to be put on hold as missing context.

Comment: FYI, I don't mind fixing your formatting, but if you're going to be asking more questions here, it might be beneficial for you to learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can format your questions correctly yourself.

Comment: just put it as $(P(x)/Q(x))^n$ done.

Answer (score 0):

The limit
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} (x^2+1)^{1/2}-2(x^3+x)^{1/3}+(x^4+x^2)^{1/4}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}-2\sqrt[3]{1+x^{-2}}+\sqrt[4]{1+x^{-2}}}{x^{-1}}.
$$
Consider that, if $\alpha >0$, then as $x\to 0$ we have
$$
(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x + O(x^2).
$$
It follows that 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}\right)-2\left(1+\frac{1}{3}x^{-2}\right)+\left(1+\frac{1}{4}x^{-2}\right)+O(x^{-4})}{x^{-1}}
$$
is equal to
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{12}x^{-2}+O(x^{-4})}{x^{-1}}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$A=(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{1/2} - 2(1 + \frac{1}{x^2})^{1/3} +(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^{1/4} $$ and define $y=\frac 1{x^2}$ which makes $$A=(1+y)^{1/2} - 2(1 + y)^{1/3} +(1+y)^{1/4} $$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem $$(1+y)^n=1+n y+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} y^2+\cdots$$ Apply to each piece; if no mistake, this would give $$A=\frac{y}{12}+\frac{y^2}{288}+\cdots=\frac{1}{12x^2}+\frac{1}{288x^4}+\cdots$$ making $$A x=\frac{1}{12x}+\frac{1}{288x^3}+\cdots$$

**Edit**

Just for the fun, use $x=10$; use your pocket calculator to get $A\approx 0.000833674$ while, just limited to the first term, the approximation gives $A\approx \frac 1{120}\approx 0.00833333$. Using the two terms $A\approx\frac{2401}{2880000}\approx 0.000833681$.

Answer (score 0):

We have so much room here we can throw caution to the wind. All we need is: If $0< p \le 1$ and $h>0,$ then

$$1\le (1+h)^p \le 1+h.$$

So your second displayed expression is at least $x(1-2(1+1/x^2) + 1) = -2/x,$ and is no more than $x(1 + 1/x^2 -2 + 1 + 1/x^2) = 2/x.$ By the squeeze theorem the desired limit is $0.$